# Why are some location cells highlighted yellow

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I created a table with columns for latitude and longitude.  I manually entered a few values in them.  Some of these cells are highlighted yellow even though the map can plot the location.  Is there a reason why they are yellow?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug I'm working on fixing :-)  Normally the yellow highlight in location columns means the value hasn't been geocoded, but for lat/long columns that obviously makes no sense. During updates the point loses track of the fact that it's a lat/long not in need of geocoding, so it's displayed in yellow. If you reload the page, or even leave the tab and come back, it should go back to normal.